# Do I need to copy DESIGNINFO, Dialog Info and AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT related code from rc file if I try to move a dialog from one project to another?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am working on a MFC VS2013 project, try to move some dialog from one project to another. My following steps is :

> find this dialog resource ID(eg.IDD_DIALOG1)
>
> search this ID in project name.rc file
>
> copy related code to target project.rc file
>
> copy related *.h and *.cpp files to target project

Now my question is, when I search the projectname.rc file. Actually I find several places in this file related to this ID. Do I need to move all these locations to new resource file? or I only need to move location1's code?
What is the meaning for location2,3 and 4?

```
//Location1:
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 239, 190
STYLE DS_SETFONT | WS_CHILD | WS_DISABLED | WS_CAPTION
CAPTION "Settings"
FONT 9, "Tahoma", 0, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    CONTROL         " Default to Use",IDC_CHECK_USE,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,6,6,222,8
    GROUPBOX        "Test2",IDC_STATIC,6,18,228,48,NOT WS_VISIBLE
    LTEXT           "Test1:",IDC_STATIC,12,32,132,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_GES_EDIT_PROC_INTERVAL,150,30,78,12,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_GROUP
......
END

//Location2:
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_DIALOG1, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 231
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 186
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED

//Location3:
//
// Dialog Info
//

IDD_DIALOG1 DLGINIT
BEGIN
    IDC_GDD_COMBO_ANGLE, 0x403, 5, 0
0x6f4e, 0x656e, "\000" 
...
    0
END

//Location4:
//
// AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
//

IDD_DIALOG1 AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT 
BEGIN
    0x0000
END
```

Comment: `#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED` -- I wouldn't recommend trying to take an APP studio created resource file and edit or mimic it by hand.

Comment: Visual Studio's resource editor can regenerate `DESIGNINFO` information, you don't need to copy it. I think the tricky part is copying ID's. VS likes to create resource IDs by itself, it uses other values like `_APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE` to keep track. You should make backup copies in case of irreversible failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to copy all except the DESIGNINFO (in the meaning of: that all others are required, DESIGNINFO may be useful). This information are just the helping lines and margins defined for the resource. They are not compiled and not needed at run time. They are helpful in the design time.

The easiest approach to copy resources from one resource into another is to open both rc files in the same Visual Studio session. Than select the one dialog copy & paste into the second RC file. This will copy all you need including the needed IDs.

Comment: Worth noting that the `DESIGNINFO` (while optional) *can* be copied, so that you get the same design-time experience in the resource editor in the new project. In this particular case it only contains the default dialog margins, that are helpful in creating a consistent looking UI.

Comment: Changed my answer